What is the difference between ++p and p+1 in C?
I'm learning C and have come across two expressions that seem similar but appear to behave differently: ++p and p+1.
Here's an example where I saw some unexpected results:
int i=0;
printf("%d \n", i);   //0
printf("%d \n", i+1); //1
printf("%d \n", ++i); //1

but
char str[] = "Hello";
char *p = str;
printf("%c \n", *p);   //'H'
printf("%c \n", *p+1); //'I'
printf("%c \n", *++p); //'e'

Could someone explain:

why *p+1 output != *++p output the pointer?


Because of operator precedence - *p+1 will be interpreted as (*p)+1, whereas *++p will be interpreted as *(++p). Indirection has a higher precedence than addition (2 vs 4). prefix increment and indirection have the same precedence (2), but have right-to-left associativity.

Also note that p++ alters p while p+1 does not. Also be aware of the difference between p++ and ++p regarding the value of the expression vs. the modification of p.

Also *(p+1) is bad style and you just found out one reason why. It should be p[1].

You can read *p+1 as (*p)+1, so it finds *p first, which is 'H', and then adds 1, which is 'I'. You can read *++p as *(++p), so it adds 1 to the pointer first and then dereferences it to get 'e'.
Here is a reference for operator precedence: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence
Higher precedence means that the operator will "happen" first. You can see that ++ is higher in precedence than *, and * is higher in precedence than +.

This leads us to the title of your question:

What is the difference between ++p and p+1 in C?

If you understand the operator precedence part above, you will see that there is no p+1 in printf("%c \n", *p+1);. You expect *p+1 to be treated like *(p+1) when operator precedence in fact tells us that it will be treated as (*p)+1, as already noted above.

The question actually asks two different questions. One in the title, another in the textual description.
Question 1 : What is the difference between ++p and p+1 in C?
The two expressions gives the same result. The difference is that ++p modifies p by incrementing it's value while p+1 doesn't change p.
The equivalent of ++p is not p+1. The equivalent of ++p is p=p+1 which can also be written as p+=1.
Example:
int i;
int result;

i = 0;
result = i+1;
printf("result is %d, i is %d\n", result, i);

i= 0;
result = ++i;
printf("result is %d, i is %d\n", result, i);

i=0;
result = (i = i+1);  // Parentheses not needed but used for clarity
printf("result is %d, i is %d\n", result, i);

i=0;
result = (i += 1);  // Parentheses not needed but used for clarity
printf("result is %d, i is %d\n", result, i);

Output:
result is 1, i is 0
result is 1, i is 1
result is 1, i is 1
result is 1, i is 1

Notice that the first line (i+1 expression) differs from the others by not changing i.
Question 2 : why *p+1 output differs from *++p output when p is a char pointer?
Due to operator precedence, the two expression are doing different things.
*p+1 will be evaluated as:

char temp = *p, i.e. read the character p points to.
char result = temp+1, i.e. increment the temp char.

So if p points to the string literal "Hello", the expression will read the character 'H' and then increment 'H' to get the final result 'I'.
*++p will be evaluated as:

++p, i.e. increment p
*p, i.e. read the character the incremented p points to

So if p points to the string literal "Hello", the expression will increment p so that it points to the character 'e' and then read the character to get the final result 'e'.
So besides having different results, the expressions also differs with respect to the value of p after evaluation.
The "problem" could be "partly fixed" by changing *p+1 to *(p+1). Then the result would be the same as *++p but the value of p would still differ.
To get exactly the same, the equivalent of *++p would be *(p = p+1).
char str[] = "Hello";
char *p;
char result;

p = str;
result = *p+1;
printf("result is %c, p points to %p\n", result, (void*)p);

p = str;
result = *++p;
printf("result is %c, p points to %p\n", result, (void*)p);

p = str;
result = *(p = p+1);
printf("result is %c, p points to %p\n", result, (void*)p);

Output (exact pointer values may differ from execution to execution):
result is I, p points to 0x7ffcfc2fc921
result is e, p points to 0x7ffcfc2fc922
result is e, p points to 0x7ffcfc2fc922

So *p+1 differs both in result and final p value.
*++p and *(p=p+1) gives the same result and final p value.
